# Web workers terminating abruptly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, worker

I initiated a web worker on chrome and it had a simple function that was called repeatedly using `setTimeout`. Surprisingly the web worker terminated after the function was called around 1000 times. Can anyone explain why? I guess chrome is doing some optimization.

**webworker.js**

```
function hi() {
    postMessage('1');
    setTimeout(hi, 1);
}
hi();
```

**main.js**

```
var blob = new Blob([code]);
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
worker.onmessage = function(data) {
    console.log(data.data); // gets called around 1000 times and done
};
```

---

EDIT:
Reproduced in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/meovfpv3/1/
It seems to takes arbitrarily long for the onmessage callback to stop firing, as quickly as a few seconds and as long as +5 mins

Comment: Sure we can explain why, but don't ask us to guess it. You'll have to show a **minimal verifyable example** so we can test it out.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel i've updated the question with the worker.js code. Basically I make a blob out of a string and give it to the worker

Comment: I am having the same issue. I've found that the Workers don't terminate (tested with a `console.log`), the onmessage callback just stops being fired at some point. Very strange, and unacceptable browser behaviour! *table flip*

Comment: Maybe the message queue is filling up or something like that?

Comment: or perhaps your workers are being garbage collected, which will happen (I think) if you don't keep references to them around.

Comment: Related/dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770415/my-javascript-web-workers-are-dying-silently-at-random-places-how-can-i-debug-t

Answer (score 5):

Here is my best guess at what is happening. By posting a message from the Web Worker every 1ms, you are demanding that the main thread processes each posted message within 1ms.

If the main thread isn't able to process the message within 1ms, you are still sending it a new message even though it isn't finished processing the last message. I would imagine this puts it into a queue of messages waiting to be processed.

Now since you are sending messages from the web worker faster than they can be processed, this queue of unprocessed messages is going to get bigger and bigger. At some point Chrome is going to throw up its hands and say "There are too many messages in the queue", and instead of queueing new messages for processing, it drops them.

This is why if you use a reasonable number in your timeout like 100ms, the message has plenty of time to be processed before the next message is sent, and no problem with unprocessed messages occurs.

---

I've created a jsFiddle where the worker sends a message to the main thread, and the main thread sends the message back to the worker. If that process doesn't happen before the next message is sent, the counters in both threads will be mismatched and the web worker will terminate.

http://jsfiddle.net/meovfpv3/3/

You can see that with a reasonable setTimeout of 100ms, all messages have adequate time to process before the next message occurs.

When you lower the setTimeout to 1ms, the message chain doesn't have time to finish before the next message is sent and the counters in each thread become eventually desynced, tripping the `if` clause and terminating the web worker.

---

One way to fix this problem is instead of blindly posting a message every 1ms whether the last one has been processed or not, only post a new message after you have received a message back from the main thread. This means that you are only posting messages as fast as the main thread can process them.

---

For completeness here is a copy of the [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/meovfpv3/3/):

Worker:

```
  var counter2 = 0;
  var rcvd = true;
  function hi() {
    counter2++;
    console.log("")
    console.log("postMessage", counter2)
    postMessage(counter2);
    if (!rcvd) {
        self.close();
      console.log("No message received");
    }
    rcvd = false;
    setTimeout(hi, 1);
  }
  hi();
  onmessage = function(e) {
    rcvd = true;
    console.log("secondMessage", e.data);
  }
```

Main:

```
var ww = document.querySelector('script[type="text/ww"]'),
    code = ww.textContent,
    blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'text/javascript'}),
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobUrl),
    counter = 0;

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    counter++;
  console.log("onmessage:", counter);
  worker.postMessage(e.data);
}
```

Comment: But setTimeout won't actually execute every millisecond; at best it will execute every 10-20ms.

Comment: @torazaburo That is correct but `setTimeout` will still execute as fast as it possibly can, which is faster than the messages it creates can be processed.

Comment: Thanks Max, interesting theory. However, my original code (which is different from the OP's) was using a timeout of 85ms, so it _seems_ to debunk the theory.  I'm not even sure the original jsfiddle I added does it justice, as the problem does seem to reproduce reliably. Unfortunately, I can't provide my entire use case in the fiddle as there is confidential code.

Looks like you'll get the bounty anyway (A for effort!), unless someone else can point out the problem. I suspect the problem is new with Chrome v50.2xx, and something to do with Web Worker optimizations

Comment: @AnsonKao Very interesting. I imagine if you do a timing measurement on the message processing function in your main thread, it is consistently processing the messages in under 85ms, correct? (If it takes more than that on average, the queue would still grow.)

Comment: I tend to doubt that Chrome would feel so overwhelmed with 1000 pending messages that it would throw up its hands and kill workers or throw away messages.

Comment: @torazaburo I would tend to believe that too, though I doubt that the queue is designed to hold more than a few messages during normal usage. Also, the main thread would be the most critical part for the browser to take shortcuts with to make sure JavaScript continues running smoothly on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, a couple of observations, which I cannot explain but are kind of interesting and might be inspirational for someone:

- @Anson - If I put your jsFiddle code into [Codepen](http://codepen.io/lesleya/pen/OXPZPE?editors=1010) (still in Chrome) there are no problems there. The `onmessage` callback just keeps working!
- And back in jsFiddle... It fails even changing the `setTimeout` to a long gap like 10s so it's not the number of times that the worker posts a message, it's how long before the `onmessage` callback stops firing – which has a lot of variance.

Then I found some ways to keep the `onmessage` handler alive in this specific example:

- Add a button/link in the html and a handler (I used jQuery) that will terminate the worker on click. Just adding this code fixes it. `$("#stop").on("click",function(e){e.preventDefault();worker.terminate();});`
- Just add `console.log(worker)` after defining `onmessage`.
- Inspired by an answer posted in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770415/my-javascript-web-workers-are-dying-silently-at-random-places-how-can-i-debug-t) you can also simply add `window.worker = worker` after defining `onmessage`.

Something about mentioning `worker` again in all cases seems to keep it alive.

Comment: Of course this will work. You have a reference to the worker. So it wont be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to postMessage every 1ms? Then you probably meant to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(function(){
    postMessage('1');
}, 1);
```

**Edit:** I incorrectly saw recursion which wasn't there, just because I was looking for it. I would still use `setInterval` over `setTimeout` though.

Comment: What's the difference? `hi()` is **not** calling itself recursively. It's calling itself in a callback, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: There is no difference (except maybe a performance difference which isn't relevant).

Comment: @torazaburo Well that's an embarrassing mistake I made! I guess the main difference is readability?!